# Error shown when voting on deleted comments does not use the new Stacks Notices component

Tags: feature-request, comments, design

When I attempt to vote on a deleted post, the error shown uses the [Stacks Notices component](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices/):

[image]

However, when I attempt to vote on a comment on a deleted post, an old-style error message is shown, instead of a floating toast notice.

[image]

Should that be updated to use the new Stacks Notices component too?

**Note:** This is from a non-SO site where there is no dark mode.

Comment: Related: [Make the text "Post has been deleted" popup brighter on a deleted post in Dark Mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403523/4642212).

Comment: I do like how the mood shifts from *You moved my cheese, put it back* to *Please move my cheese quicker* ...