# Can we have the error shown when close-voting a deleted question use the Stacks Notices component?

Tags: feature-request, design, vote-to-close, deleted-posts

When you attempt to up/downvote a deleted post, it shows an error that uses the [Stacks Notices](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices/) component:

[image]

But if you vote to close a deleted question, it shows an older message:

[image]

Which... is kind of obvious.  Can we have that show the same [toasty error message](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices/#toast)?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359501/error-shown-when-voting-on-deleted-comments-does-not-use-the-new-stacks-notices

Comment: @KodosJohnson true, but that's for comments, not Q/A's.

Comment: I know, I still thought it would be helpful to link it even though it's only slightly related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Close-voting a deleted question now results in a much better-looking Stacks message:

[image]